# Scroll Bars Won't work in mfc application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, scrollbar

I have a view class for my mfc app that inherits the CSrollView class for supposedly easy scroll bar support.  I can get the scroll bars to appear at a certain point, like when I zoom in on the stuff displayed in the view, but when I try to scroll over to the left, nothing happens.  I have researched this online for a couple of hours and I can't pinpoint what I am doing incorrectly. Here's my OnDraw() and OnInitialUpdate() methods in the view class:

```
void CWaveEditView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CWaveEditDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
// TODO: add draw code for native data here
    WaveFile * wave = &pDoc->wave;

    if (wave->hdr==NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Get dimensions of the window.
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);


    // Set color in pen and brush for wave
    COLORREF color = RGB( 0, 255, 0 );
    CPen pen2( PS_SOLID, 0, color );
    pDC->SelectObject( &pen2 );
    CBrush brush2(color);
    pDC->SelectObject( &brush2 );

     // Draw selection if any
    if (selectionStart != selectionEnd) {
        pDC->Rectangle(selectionStart, 0, selectionEnd, rect.Height());
    }

    // Draw the wave
    pDC->MoveTo(0,0);
    int x;
    for (x=0; x < zoomAmount*wave->lastSample/scaling; x++) {
        // Assuming the whole file will be fit in the window, for every x value in the window
        // we need to find the equivalent sample in the wave file.
        float val = wave->get_sample((int) (x*scaling/zoomAmount) );

        // We need to fit the sound also in the y axis. The y axis goes from 0 in the
        // top of the window to rect.Height at the bottom. The sound goes from -32768 to 32767
        // we scale it in that way.
        int y = (int) ((val+32768) * (rect.Height()-1) / (32767+32768));
        pDC->LineTo(x,rect.Height() - y);
    }
    CSize totalSize;
    totalSize.cx = x;
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT,totalSize);
}

void CWaveEditView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();

    // Initial scroll sizes
    CSize sizeTotal;
    CRect rect;
    CWaveEditDoc *doc = GetDocument();
    WaveFile * wave = &doc->wave;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    scaling = wave->lastSample/rect.Width();
    sizeTotal.cx = 700;
    sizeTotal.cy = 700;
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, sizeTotal);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an OnScroll function? If so, what does it do?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  I had the class inheriting correctly in the header file, but mfc generates some code where I had forgot to change the inheritance to CScrollView.  MFC is the biggest cluster f*** that I have ever seen, I'm only using it for a school project because we have to.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. MFC isn't great but it's better than writing Windows apps without a framework! I believe Qt is better but sadly have not been able to try it. At least these days we have the stl to use instead of a lot of MFC dross....

Comment: Just a note: Never try to call a function like SetScrollSizes in OnDraw! This should cause problems with unneeded recursion... OnDraw is only for drawing. When the View changes (OnUpdate) you shoulkd set the scroll sizes.